# Creating a buffer using an 'embedded python block'

Tags: python, gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

Im trying to create a program in GNU Radio that will store data from a signal into a Filesink. However, by doing that, most of the data in the filesink will consist of noise. My goal is to only  store the main signal and a little bit of the noise before and after that same signal.

To accomplish that im trying to build a buffer, using the 'embedded python block', that will only store the main signal and, as mentioned above, a little bit of the noise before and after that signal (the size of the stored noise is determined by the size of the buffer).

For that i created this GNU Radio program  [GNU Radio Program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXzcj.png)  where at the end i connected a filesink to the squelch block and a filesink to the buffer block so that i could compare both of the filesinks using a spectrum analyzer.

(Note: Im emitting a signal using a transmitter and an arduino. The arduino was programmed to send an "Hello World" message every second. I then use an SDR-Pluto to capture that signal/message).

The main problem is that after i run the program, the squelch filesink will only have 64KB, regardless of how long i leave the program running. On the other hand, the buffer filesink will store data, as time passes, however, when i inspect the buffer filesink on a spectrum analyzer, the spectrum is empty.

If anyone could help me understand what the problem is i would be extremely grateful.
Here is my buffer code:

```
import numpy as np
from gnuradio import gr


class blk(gr.basic_block):  # other base classes are basic_block, decim_block, interp_block

    def __init__(self, buffer_size_param=10000.0):  # only default arguments here
        """arguments to this function show up as parameters in GRC"""
        gr.basic_block.__init__(
            self,
            name='Embedded Python Block (Buffer)',  # will show up in GRC
            in_sig=[np.complex64, np.complex64],
            out_sig=[np.complex64]
        )
        
        self.buffer = [] 
        self.buffer_size_param = buffer_size_param
        self.counter = self.buffer_size_param
 
    def general_work(self, input_items, output_items):
        squelch = input_items[0]
        throttle = input_items[1]
        
        for i in range(len(squelch)):       
            
            if (squelch [i] == 0):
                self.counter = self.counter + 1
                if (self.counter <= buffer_size_param):
                    output_items.append(throttle[i])
                else:
                    self.buffer.append(throttle [i])
                    
                    if len (self.buffer) > buffer_size_param:
                            self.buffer.pop (0)
                            
            else:
        
                output_items = output_items + self.buffer
                output_items.append(throttle[i])
                
                self.buffer = []
                self.counter = 0
        
        return len(output_items)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, I implemented a circular buffer with numpy and it works quite well.
You can generate a buffer using Numpy, it is quite fast for a code written pure python.
If you see any bug, please let me know
https://github.com/OkanErturk16/Misc/blob/master/circularBuffer.py

Comment: Please include your code in answer, not just a link.